# Using the If statement to clear a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a userform to enter address data. I have a text box for address name, combo box to select road, street, etc., and 4 numeric boxes for odd from and to, evens from and to.

The issue I have is getting VBA to clear the contents of the "to" boxes if numbers have already been inputted into them but the user them changes the from boxes to a number of greater value the the "to" boxes after.

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
Private Sub txtstreet_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
  Select Case KeyAscii
    Case 65 To 90
    Case 97 To 122
    Case 32
    Case 127
    Case Else
      KeyAscii = 0
  End Select
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  roaddesciptor.List = Array("ROAD", "STREET", "WAY", "AVENUE", "DRIVE", "GROVE", "LANE", "GARDENS", "PLACE", "CRESENT", "CLOSE", "SQUARE", "HILL", "CIRCUS", "MEWS", "VALE", "RISE", "ROW", "MEAD", "WHARF")
  roaddesciptor.ListIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub txtaddoddfrom_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
  Select Case KeyAscii
    Case 48 To 57
    Case Else
      KeyAscii = 0
  End Select
End Sub

Private Sub txtaddoddfrom_AfterUpdate()
  If txtaddoddfrom.Value < txtaddoddto.Value Or txtaddoddto = "" And txtaddoddfrom.Value Mod 2 = 1 Then Exit Sub
  If txtaddoddfrom.Value Mod 2 <> 1 Or txtaddoddfrom.Value > txtaddoddto.Value Then txtaddoddfrom = ""
  'Else: txtaddoddfrom = ""
End Sub

Private Sub txtaddoddto_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
  Select Case KeyAscii
         Case 48 To 57
         Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub txtaddoddto_AfterUpdate()
  If txtaddoddto.Value Mod 2 = 1 And txtaddoddto.Value >= txtaddoddfrom.Value Then Exit Sub
  If txtaddoddto.Value Mod 2 <> 1 Or txtaddoddto.Value < txtaddoddfrom.Value Then txtaddoddto = ""
End Sub

Private Sub txtaddevenfrom_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
  Select Case KeyAscii
    Case 48 To 57
    Case Else
      KeyAscii = 0
  End Select
End Sub

Private Sub txtaddevenfrom_AfterUpdate()
  If txtaddevenfrom.Value < txtaddevento.Value Or txtaddevento = 0 And txtaddevenfrom.Value Mod 2 <> 1 Then Exit Sub
  If txtaddevenfrom.Value Mod 2 = 1 Or txtaddevenfrom.Value > txtaddevento.Value Then txtaddevenfrom = ""
End Sub

Private Sub txtaddevento_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
  Select Case KeyAscii
    Case 48 To 57
    Case Else
      KeyAscii = 0
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub txtaddevento_AfterUpdate()
  If txtaddevento.Value Mod 2 <> 1 And txtaddevento.Value >= txtaddevenfrom.Value Then Exit Sub
  If txtaddevento.Value Mod 2 = 1 Or txtaddevento.Value < txtaddevenfrom.Value Then txtaddevento = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: you can shorten your code by using `If Not IsNumeric(Chr(KeyAscii)) Then KeyAscii = 0` to check for numeric input. ..... also use this type of statements to make code clearer `Case Asc("a") To Asc("z")`  ....  the `case 127` line appears to be included by mistake

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, you want to add code to the AfterUpdate event of the "From" box, that will erase the "To" box if the new "From" box number is great than the "To" box number.

If you add the below line of code to your "From" box AfterUpdate event, it should do what you want. It's the same as you already have, except that you are clearing the "From" box, instead of the "To" box.

```
txtaddoddfrom.Value > txtaddoddto.Value Then txtaddoddto = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues to deal with here.

First, you can't use numerical operators on strings, which is what a blank field is. The are a number of different ways to allow for this. One way is `(0 & "")`. Another is to explicitly check for them. I use both in my adjustment of your code.

Second, attempting to change a field's value that you are about to tab into fails. You have to wrap `Application.EnableEvents` statements around the attempt for it to succeed.

Lastly, you were zapping the "from" field instead of the "to" field in the "from" handler.

Here's a pair of your handlers fixed:

```
Private Sub txtaddoddfrom_AfterUpdate()
  If (0 & txtaddoddfrom) Mod 2 <> 1 Then txtaddoddfrom = "" ' If even (or ""), zap it
  If txtaddoddfrom = "" Or txtaddoddto = "" Then Exit Sub 'If was even or blank, done -> exit
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If txtaddoddto < txtaddoddfrom Then txtaddoddto.Value = "" ' Otherwise compare and zap txtaddoddto if smaller
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Private Sub txtaddoddto_AfterUpdate()
  If (0 & txtaddoddto) Mod 2 <> 1 Then txtaddoddto = "" ' If even (or ""), zap it
  If txtaddoddto = "" Or txtaddoddfrom = "" Then Exit Sub 'If was even or blank, done -> exit
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If txtaddoddfrom > txtaddoddto Then txtaddoddfrom = "" ' Otherwise compare and zap txtaddoddfrom if greater
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note: Fields values can be accessed by using `.Value` explicitly, or implicitly without it. It's a good idea to consistently use one form or the other.